# Excel - how to join two formulas into one - SUBSTITUTE(CELL) & SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CELL))

Tags: excel

In Excel I am trying to join two formulas together to get the following result:

```
c: \ Users \ Administration \ Forms \ Progress Notes.xlsx
```

*I am happy with both the formulas below*, however, I just need to know how to join them both together into one large formula e.g.

1)  This adds spaces between the `\` (THANKS to Liyan Chang for solving this):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"), "\", " \ ")
```

2)  This removes the *Worksheet Name* & removes the `[` & `]` around the filename.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CELL("filename"), FIND("]", CELL("filename"), 1)-1), "[", "")
```

I have tried tried several ways of combining the two formulas into one, but keep getting error messages.

Comment: You've given the result but not the original string?

Comment: whats the original string?

Comment: try this: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CELL("filename"), FIND("]", CELL("filename"), 1)-1), "[", ""), "\", " \ ")`

Comment: Thank you so much Andreas - it now works perfectly - greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CELL("filename"), FIND("]", CELL("filename"), 1)-1), "[", ""),"\"," \ ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chris Neilsen - it now works perfectly - greatly appreciated.